# Lucene4 get a single word from compund word

Tags: lucene.net

I'm looking for a way to get a word from a compound word ie. I index "automobile" and I need to search for "auto". I could do this with wrapping the search string with wildcard characters, but I need to know if its possible with default configurations.

I have tried ShingleFilter, but it doesn't seem to work well enough.
Here is my custom analyzer that I have tried

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    private LuceneVersion _version;

    public CustomAnalyzer(LuceneVersion luceneVersion)
    {
        _version = luceneVersion;
    }

    protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(reader);

        ShingleFilter filter = new ShingleFilter(tokenizer, 2);
        filter.SetTokenSeparator(string.Empty);            
        TokenStream tokenStream = filter;
        
        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer, tokenStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. It is about using NGramTokenizer in my custom analyzer. Here is the code for the fellow wizards needing it:

```
public class CustomAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    private LuceneVersion _version;

    public CustomAnalyzer(LuceneVersion luceneVersion)
    {
        _version = luceneVersion;
    }

    protected override TokenStreamComponents CreateComponents(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        Tokenizer tokenizer = new NGramTokenizer(_version, reader);

        return new TokenStreamComponents(tokenizer);
    }
}
```